# Why is C++ so much faster than C in this code?

Tags: gcc, optimization, g++

My C code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
  char* a = (char*)malloc(200000);
  for (int i = 0;i< 100000;i++){
  strcat(a,"b");
  }
  printf("%s",a);
}
```

My C++ code is

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void){
  std::string a = "";
  for (int i = 0;i< 100000;i++){
    ¦ a+="b";
  }

  std::cout<<a;
}
```

On my machine, the C code runs in about 5 seconds, while on my machine, the C++ code runs in 0.025! seconds.

Now, the C code doesn't check for overflows, has no C++ overhead, classes and yet is quite a few magnitudes slower than my C++ code.

Using gcc/g++ 6.2.0 compiled with -O3 on Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Probably because `strcat()` is a library function that will not be inlined, whereas `std::string` is a (specialisation of) a templated class, so operations are - depending on optimisation settings - more likely to be inlined. There is also the fact that your C version dynamically allocates a much larger buffer than needed and, depending on available resources on your system, that can slow operations down.   Note that your C++ code is not guaranteed to compile, since `<iostream>` is not required to define `std::string`.

Comment: I would guess that C uses a null-terminated string so `strcat` has search for the end of string. The c++ string does not need to do this and therefore the concatenation is much faster.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Wow. Shlemiel's paint algorithm at work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@erwin was correct.

When I change my code to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void mystrcat(char* src,char* dest,int lenSrc){
  src[lenSrc]=dest[0];
}
int main(void){
  char* a = (char*)malloc(200000);
  for (int i = 0;i< 100000;i++){
  mystrcat(a,"b",i);
  }
  a[100000] = 0;
  printf("%s\n",a);
}
```

It takes about .012s to run (mostly printing the large screen).

[Shlemiel's the painter's algorithm](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) at work!